# Using neutral or basic alumina in column chromatography for purification of amines

Tags: organic-chemistry, chromatography, purification

I am conducting a synthesis involving amines, and it is found that some spots still hardly moves from the starting point in spite of the dichloromethane 9:methanol 1 eluent condition. Addition of triethylamine doesn't seem to help the situation because I'm guessing there are two different compounds in the streak (that is they are similar in Rf and hardly move from the starting point). So I am considering using alumina TLC plate for identification and alumia column chromatography for purification. Here are the questions with it.

1. There are two types (except acidic) of alumina, neutral and basic. Is it sufficient to use neutral one for amines? Or should I use basic one?
2. Are all procedures same to the column chromatography using silica?

Comment: Either alumina will potentially work. The procedures are similar to silica chromatography.  I have extensively used ammonia in MeOH with DCM for silica chromatography of amines.